# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywhatkit' VENV

Tags: python, automation, screen-scraping

I'm new to programming, this is the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywhatkit'`, I installed the module using pip, also tried pip3, the modules are installed in a env, the env is activated.

I'm using:

- Windows 11
- Scoop.sh
- Python 3.10 and Pip 22.1
- VSCode, CMD, and Powershell

I check that I'm using the correct interpreter path which is located at `~\scoop\apps\python\current\python.exe`.

I installed the virtual environment globally using `pip install virtualenv` then `virtualenv wa` and activated using `wa\Scripts\activate`.

I ran the command `python -m site`, output below:

```
sys.path = [
    'C:\Users\warner\programming-projects',
    'C:\Users\warner\scoop\apps\python\current\python310.zip',
    'C:\Users\warner\scoop\apps\python\current\DLLs',
    'C:\Users\warner\scoop\apps\python\current\lib',
    'C:\Users\warner\scoop\apps\python\current',
    'C:\Users\warner\scoop\apps\python\current\lib\site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: 'C:\Users\warner\AppData\Roaming\Python' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: 'C:\Users\warner\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages' (doesn't exist)
```

When I ran this command I did it having the **venv** deactivated, then I run it activated and the output was the same.

Lastly I invoked python using the `where` command, there was not output.

Comment: is this a problem specific to only the `pywhatkit` library?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's only a pywhatkit problem, at the moment I haven't been able to solve problem. It seems that it has something to do with the virtualenv, I'm working right now in the bot, I had to install the modules globally, for some reason looks like virtualenv is not working along with modules.